# Generating Functions and stars and bars

Tags: discrete-mathematics

In the expansion of

$(1+x+x^{2}+------x^{27})(1+x+x^{2}------x^{14})^{2} $

what is the coefficient of $x^{28}$?

Can someone please tell me what I did wrong

This can be interpreted as a 28 sided die with numbers from [0,27] and 2 15 sided dice's with numbers from [0,15] and we are trying to find the number of ways these dices can add up to 28

So now using stars and bars we have the following

$27-a+14-b+14-c=28$

Now that equals

$a+b+c=27$

So now the answer is 
${28 \choose 2}=378$

Comment: In your equation a,b,c can be anything from 0 to 27. Is that allowed? Shouldn't b and C be bounded by 14?

Comment: Is there a way to use stars and bars to solve this problem though. My idea of using 27-a,14-b and 14-c was so I could restrict the bound but I forgot to account for b and c being greater than 14

Comment: We get $x^a$ from the first factor ($1+\ldots +x^{27}$), $x^b$ from the second and $x^c$ from the third (both $1+\ldots +x^{14}$). Pick $b\in\{0,14\}$ then pick $c\in \{0,14\}$. This overcounts $1$ case ($b=c=0$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ones you overcounted were the solutions to

$$
a+b+c=27\\
b>14 \; \text{or} \; c>14
$$

Counting the number of solutions where $b>14$ gives

$$
a + (b-14) + (c) = 27 -14
$$

Counting the number of solutions where $c>14$ gives

$$
a + b + (c-14) = 27 -14
$$

There are no solutions with both $b,c>14$.

So do stars and bars on these two cases and subtract it off from your previous answer.